# SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am a beginner in databases. What edition of sql server i should start with?

Next the project i have to work on is a simple project and needs a small database.
i downloaded the SQL server 2005 express edition from microsoft's site and installed it. It showed me SQL server configuration manager , SQL server surface area configuration and sql server error and usage reporting.

i dont know what to install further to get the interface of creating tables, running my queries and producing my database?

Comment: You need SQL Server Management Studio Express

Comment: *"needs an urgent reply"* - the easiest way to make your question unpopular

Comment: Are you sure you need Microsoft SQL Server? There are several other good choices that aren't as complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start learning something new, I can assure you nothing is urgent. It will take **many** days (years, in fact) until you have the knowledge you seek.

Right now, get the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25174) along with the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985). This contains a management tool that allows you to create tables and run queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) to manage your databases.